# How to associate Bernouli numbers or Bernouli polynomials into the relation $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[n(4x-1)+(2x) \right]x^n=0$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

How to associate Bernouli numbers or Bernouli polynomials into the relation
\begin{equation} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left[n(4x-1)+(2x) \right]x^n=0, \ \ \ \cdots 
\cdots  (1) \end{equation} and \begin{equation} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left[n^2(4x-1)^2+(2x+12x^2) \right]x^n=0, \ \ \ \cdots 
\cdots  (2) \end{equation}

**My approach:**

The Bernouli numbers are

$B_0=0, \ B_1=-1/2, \ B_2=1/6, \ B_4=-1/30, \cdots$ and $B_{2n+1}=0,n =1,2,3,.....$,

where as the Bernouli polynomials are

$B_0(x)=1, \\
B_1(x)=x-1/2, \\
B_2(x)=x^2-x+1/6 \\
B_3(x)=x^3-3/2x^2+1/2x, \cdots$.

I think Bernouli polynomials can be used in $(1)$ and $(2)$ but I could not.

Please help me.

**Next,**

I have seen a note where it is given \begin{eqnarray} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x-1]x^n=-1   \end{eqnarray} From this equation,putting $x=1, \ x=-1$ 
\begin{eqnarray} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!nx^n=-1, \ x=1 \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!(-1)^n(n+2)=1, \ x=-1  \end{eqnarray}
and then it writes \begin{eqnarray}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)B_{n+1}-B_n]=1, \ ........(*)  \end{eqnarray}, where $B_n$ are Bernouli numbers in $(*)$.

I did not understand the process of associating Bernouli numbers.

Can I use the same process in $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

Kindly help me

Comment: You are very confused. Your equation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x-1]x^n=-1$ is only true as a "formal power series" equation. You can't substitute $x=1$ or $x=-1$ in it. The value of $\sum_{n=0}^k n![(n+1)B_{n+1}-B_n]$ is $-1$ if $k$ is even, otherwise not so simple but is Bernoulli multiplied by factorials.

Comment: @Somos, why only formal power series? It converges surely and hence we have convergence and so it is a power series. For $x=\pm 1$ the power series converges and in fact it invariant sum

Comment: The finite sum $\sum_{n=0}^k n![(n+1)x-1]x^n = -1+ (k+1)!x^{k+1}$ which converges as $k\to\infty$ only in the sense of "formal power series".

Comment: @Somos, Actually I forgot to mention that here the convergence is in p-adic norm. The above equality is proven in a published paper having invariant sum

Comment: Note:  Bernoulli should be spelled with two $l$s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you may be looking for is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^k n! ((n+1) B_{n+1} - B_n) = (k+1)! B_{k+1} - 1. \tag{1}$$
 I don't see the left side converging as $\,k\to\infty.$
Similarly also we get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^k n![(n+1)x-1]x^n = (k+1)!x^{k+1} -1. \tag{2}$$
These are both example of [telescoping sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).
The step from equation $(2)$ to equation $(1)$ is a
classical one using the [Umbral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) with
the linear mapping defined by
$$ L: x^n \mapsto B_n. \tag{3} $$